# Need to show those users who have subscribed the group. i have stored users id in the members child who have joined the group

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

[image: image1]

I need to show groups in the main activity. Here I am using the if condition but I am not getting any groups.

```
if (snapshot.child("Members").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).exists());
```

Here is the whole code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        list.clear();
        
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (snapshot.child("Members").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).exists());

                Group group = dataSnapshot.getValue(Group.class);
                list.add(group);
            }
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a listener at the following reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups")
```

It means that you're reading (downloading) the entire "Groups" node. Which is actually not feasible considering the fact that under that node there may be potentially multiple nodes. So if you want to check the existence of a particular element in the Realtime Database, don't do it on the client, but perform a query:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference groupsRef = db.child("Groups");
Query queryByUid = groupsRef.orderByChild("Members/" + uid);
productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                Group group = ds.getValue(Group.class);
                list.add(group);
                Log.d("TAG", group.getGroupName());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

In this way, you'll only download the documents that match the query and nothing more. Otherwise it will be a waste of resources and bandwidth.

Comment: Hey Agam. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?